# How to display child div on the end of parent flex row div and another two divs on the start of parent div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How is it possible to display two div containers on the start of a row flex parent and the third one at the end? child-3 should be on the right side in the example below.

Here is a quick sample with all cildren on the start of the parent: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt6p4a30/1/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child-1,
.child-2,
.child-3 {
  margin: 2px 1px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child-1 {}

.child-2 {}

.child-3 {}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
    child-1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
    child-2
  </div>
  <div class="child-3">
    child-3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are comfortable with child #3 being taken out of the document flow, you can simply just position it absolutely with `right: 0` in the same parent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add `margin-left: auto;`

```css
.parent {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.child-1,
.child-2,
.child-3 {
    margin: 2px 1px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child-1 {}

.child-2 {}

.child-3 {
    margin-left: auto;    /* new line added */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
   child-1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
   child-2
  </div>
  <div class="child-3">
   child-3
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the first two elements in a div and the third one in a different div.

Give parent div `justify-content: space-between`.

Do the same with the new wrapping divs. (Make sure they are also `display: flex;`)

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jt6p4a30/2/

Your html should be

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="subparent">
  <div class="child-1">
    child-1
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
    child-2
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subparent">
  <div class="child-3">
    child-3
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.subparent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```